# Connecting a MacBook Pro to a Windows ad hoc network

Tags: windows, network, wifi, ad-hoc

I'm trying to share my wired ethernet connection from my Windows 7 laptop with my MacBook Pro (running 10.6.5). I've just set it up to be an open network; no encryption. I'm pretty sure I set up the ad hoc network correctly, it's broadcasting, and I can connect to the network on the mac.

The catch is that the network shows up under the "Devices" part of the menu, rather than the main networks area. I can't browse to any websites, nor connect to the Windows box via samba. The IP assigned is a 169.254 one.

Is there some setting somewhere that I missed to get this to work correctly? Do I need to manually set this up some how? Here are my network settings:
[image: Connection Woe]

Comment: Did you find a solution here?

Comment: Sort of... I ended up dumping the windows laptop and using the mac full time with a windows VM.

Answer (score 2):

You've set up the connection correctly, but it looks like you haven't set the Windows machine to allow other computers on the ad-hoc network to access the internet. Here are the steps you need (shamelessly taken from [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network) blog post):

*Note:* I assume that you have ensured that the Windows machine is connected to the internet through some non-wireless method. If not, you definitely need to do that first, otherwise there's nothing to share.

1. Click on the Windows icon, and type `View network connections` and press enter.
2. Identify the wired internet connection and the wireless card. Locate the wired internet connection and right click on it. Select Properties.
3. Click on the Sharing tab. Make sure the box `Allow other users to connect through this computer's internet connection` is checked.

Comment: Tried that. Got the same thing, a 169.254.x.x address and no actual network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, I would recommend an application like [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) (free and paid versions available).

I had a similar problem connecting both an iPod Touch and a Nokia WLAN capable cell phone to a Ad-hoc network from a Windows 7 laptop. After installing and setting up Connectify in Access Point I was able to connect successfully with the iPod Touch. (The Nokia could now at least see the network, but connection failed.)

Some alternatives to Connectify: 
http://alternativeto.net/software/connectify/

Answer (score 0):

If your ad hoc address is 192.168.137.1 you should set macbook's ip to 192.168.137.2 or some address like that manually (between 192.168.137.2 and 192.168.137.254) because it is an ad hoc network with no DHCP server. Set router ip to ad hoc's ip: 192.168.137.1.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system preferences > network > advanced > TCP/IP tab > on configure IPv4 dropdown click on Manually and set IPv4 address to 192.168.X.X and that will help you connect to internet.